# When to use int() and when to use var: int

Tags: python, casting, integer

I'm wondering, when do you use `var: int` and when do you use `int(var)`.

For example:

```py
def func(var: int, var2):
    print(var - int(var2))
```

Comment: `var: int` is a type hint https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html , `int` is a built-in function to transform a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var: int` declares the type of a variable that is expected to be and pass to the desired function or class, while `int(var)` will cast `var` variable to be instance of int class:

```
>> a = '3' # a is String
>> a = int(a)
>> a
out: 3 # a is Ineteger now
```

Answer (score 2):

`var: int` does essentially nothing unless you explicitely run a type checker (e.g. mypy) on your code. Without said typechecker it's just some metadata.

`int(var)` however is an actual and explicit runtime conversion. It will do nothing if `var` is already an int, but otherwise will attempt to convert `var` to an integer somehow (e.g. parsing the string or calling the object's `__index__`), and signal an error if it can not.